Can anyone explain the physics behind this 'Ryke' effect without any complicated mathematics?
If you look at this video below , the upper arm segment is not allowed to rotate about its longitudinal axis , whereas the lower segment can rotate. When allowed to swing like a double pendulum , there is no rotation of the lower segment , but when the upper arm is shifted from its plane of double pendulum motion, the lower arm rotates.
Can anyone explain the physics behind this effect without any complicated mathematics?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMkAoT1YLGE
